# How do you alter the new user registration form on expressionengine?

Tags: view, registration, expressionengine

There appears to be a view for the registration form that comes with Expressionengine 2, but modifying it does not appear to do anything for the front end.  That file is /system/expressionengine/views/members/register.php.

Where can the new user registration form be altered?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might want to post this to the EE StackExchange site: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The front end template is /themes/profile_themes/(your selected theme)/registration_form.html

You can edit this in EE via Design -> Themes -> Member Profile Templates.

I can't explain why these are static HTML files when most templates are stored in the database.

A tiny bit more info at 
http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/design/themes/member_profile_templates.html

The problem with using this is that you get the rather shoddy EE validation system - a separate page with the validation messages, from which you have to go back (!) to correct your input. They're also served up with their own header (html_header.php) and footer (html_footer.php) and inline styles (stylesheet.html), though you can use template tags and snippets etc. in them.

IMHO you're better off writing your own templates or using a plugin.